# Java EE application Hung on WAS 7.0 due to memory consumption

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-7

I have an application which is running fine on WAS 6.0 but throwing a core dump on WAS 7.0 because java threads are occupying the entire memory. It runs on a shared environment.

Has anyone faced such a problem before? I can provide the core dump if needed but I can't attach it here as a file attachment. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this.

```
1) Open RAD and Start WCS server.
2) Log on to WebSphere administration console.
3) Select Servers-->Server types -->WebSphere application servers --> server1 -->Java and process management --> Process definition -->Java virtual machine.
4) Change the value of Maximum heap size field.(Eg 512 to 1024)
5) Save and restart the server.And Republish the application.
```

Answer (score 0):

The same applies if it is not running on an development environment but in a normal environment